# YA fantasy novel: "Vampires" (Blood suckers) at a boarding school, girl lives in a forest

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, vampire

The title may have had the word "forest" in it but I DEFINITELY remember the cover having a girl walking into a forest with her back turned.

The story went something like a girl being at a boarding school I think because I remember her living with a roommate in the forest. There are these two brothers and one of them has curly hair. And the first brother is who she likes. Eventually he reveals he's a vampire or something like that and so she allows him to draw blood from her. And I explicitly remember that the blood was drawn from above her armpit.

In the end she gets together with the curly haired brother who is also a bloodsucker and he receives blood from her roommate.

Answer (score 5):

It's called *[Dark Companion](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12436013-dark-companion)* by Marta Acosta.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer. I know you're the OP, but it would help if you have a small writeup about why it's *Dark Companion*.